# "For Heaven's Sake" or "For Heaven Sakes"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I hear these used almost interchangeably.  To me "for heaven's sake" makes sense grammatically, but is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [For goodness sake!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22for+goodness+sake%22&oq=%22for+goodness+sake%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.7407&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Most people don't bother even *writing* possessive apostrophe in **goodness'** there, and no-one *ever* enunciates it (or pluralises **sakes**). But we nearly always pluralise the facetiously stereotypical [Land sakes!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22land+sakes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (which I invariably follow up with [Lawks-a-mussy!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22lawks+a+mussy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) :)

Comment: Interesting that no-one has suggested "for heavens' sake" i.e. for the sake of (all the) heavens.....

Comment: Just think which between "for my sake" or "for I sakes" sounds right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's definitely "For Heaven's Sake", as in "For the sake of Heaven". (Think "For God's Sake", "For Pete's Sake", etc.) The singular "sake" is the one that is the most standard and formal, though you also often see it as "For heaven's sakeS".

"For heaven sakes" is apparently one of the [common alternate forms](http://grammarist.com/usage/for-heavens-sake/) of the expression, but I imagine it is rather colloquial and region-dependent. I don't think I've ever heard it used, personally.

Comment: Of those listed in the link you give, "heavens' sake" is also grammatically correct, and theologically sound according to some beliefs.

Comment: That's a good point, though only if the trailing apostrophe is added. Otherwise the possessive is lost.

Comment: Yes, it's listed as one found, but not given in the examples of "grammatically questionable" uses, leaving it unclear whether they find that form questionable or not themselves.

Comment: @Jon I submit that "heaven's sake" → "heaven sake" is metanalysis.